# How can I get tokenGroups from active directory on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-4.0

I'm trying to load tokenGroups from Active Directory but it isn't working once deployed to a Windows Server (2003). I cannot figure out why, since it works fine locally...

Here is my error:

> There is no such object on the server.

And here is my code (the sid variable is the current users SecurityIdentifier pulled from HttpContext):

```
DirectoryEntry userDE = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://<SID={0}>", sid.Value))
userDE.RefreshCache(new[] { "tokenGroups" });

var tokenGroups = userDE.Properties["tokenGroups"] as CollectionBase;
groups = tokenGroups.Cast<byte[]>()
    .Select(sid => new SecurityIdentifier(sid, 0)).ToArray();
```

Any ideas why I would get that error?

**UPDATE:** The error actually happens on the RefreshCache line

Comment: Do you have a valid value for `userDE` after the constructor call?? Does that user really exist? Or do you need to provide e.g. a server to use in your LDAP path?? "No such object" seems to indicate the user just plain doesn't exist.... (or cannot be found, due to e.g. permissions)

Comment: Is it perhaps because the sid belongs to a local user on the client, instead of an active directory user?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a valid value for userDE after the constructor call?? Does that user really exist? Or do you need to provide e.g. a server to use in your LDAP path??

The error message `No such object on server` seems to indicate the user just plain doesn't exist.... (or cannot be found, due to e.g. permissions)

<strike>Try this - not sure if that's the problem, but it's worth a try - it *should* work:</strike>

```
DirectoryEntry userDE = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://<SID={0}>", sid.Value))
userDE.RefreshCache(new string[] { "tokenGroups" });
```

Try using `new string[]` instead of just `new[]`.

Comment: Ahh, let me check that... I guess because of the way this AD stuff works it might not give me the error until that RefreshCache call... i'll check on it and hopefully that's my issue

Comment: DO you really require permissions to lookup a sid?

Comment: My actual problem is that WCF is seeing the current user as Network Service instead of my account... *sigh*

Comment: I'm on my 3rd day of trying to get WCF working with Windows Authentication through a web app... I'm starting to believe it just isn't supported.

Comment: @Max: guess you need to ask a new question :)